# Is there a way to use ebook-convert to split an epub into chapters

Tags: command-line, script, automation, epub, calibre

Im looking for a way to take a book as an epub file and break it up into a series of smaller epub files for each chapter? I am aware of [the other available options with Sigil and the Epubsplit plugin for calibre](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/1069/how-can-i-extract-some-chapters-or-sections-from-an-ebook-into-a-new-one), but they both seem to work through a GUI, which precludes being able to run them over hundreds or thousands of files in a script.

Is there no way of doing this with one of the command line tools that calibre provides, such as ebook-convert, so that I can call something like

`ebook-convert someBook.epub --splitIntoChapters`

and get something like chapter1.epub, chapter2.epub, chapter3.epub... and so on in return?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an old perl library [`libebook-tools-perl`](https://metacpan.org/dist/EBook-Tools)?

[`man ebook(1p)`](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/libebook-tools-perl/ebook.1p.en.html) has some examples, taking inspiration something like this could work:

```bash
ebook unpack mybook.pdb my_book
cd my_book
mkdir split
# split document by chapters somehow with sed/awk/perl/python
cd ..
for i in my_book/split/*.xhtml; do
    base=$(basename $i ".xhtml)
    echo "generate $base"
    ebook blank $base.opf --title "My Title" --author "My Name"
    cp $i .
    ebook adddoc $base.xhtml
done

ebook fix
ebook genepub
```